# Mouse over em imagem para mostrar box de informação

Tags: html, css

Como faço para um mouse over abrir um Tooltip e esta caixa não sumir quando retirar o foco do mouse para eu consiga colocar um texto clicável dentro deste container?

Como exemplo: as tags que aparecem aqui no Stack Overflow.

Comment: Olá @Felipe, bom vindo ao [pt.so]. Até que ponto você ja chegou? pode postar um [exemplo mínimo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) como consta no topico [ask] da [help]

Comment: Acho que você esta se referindo a abrir um tooltip e não um lightbox... Você tem que controlar o hover do próprio tooltip e impedir que ele feche quando o mouse sair do elemento disparador e entrar no tooltip.

Answer (score 2):

Sua pergunta foi um tanto quanto ampla.
Com o código abaixo você conseguiria ter a funcionalidade de um `hover` atribuir visibilidade para um elemento.

CSS

```
.lightbox{
display:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="ExibirLightBox">Exibir</a>

<div class="lightbox>
// Conteudo do lightbox
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('.ExibirLightBox').hover(function (e) {
            $(".lightbox").css("display", "block");
        }
    )
    });
```

Comment: Bom dia Rafael,
Então, o que acontece é que quando uso um lightbox por exemplo prettyphoto ele abre o light box mas nao fica estatico depois.
Precisava de algo como se fossem essas tags do stack, que voce passa o mouse sobre a tag e aparece aquele box com informações e links.

Comment: Você consegue postar um exemplo no jsfiddle.net? Não entendi exatamente qual é o seu problema

Comment: já posto só um segundo.

Comment: @FelipeXavier Por favor atualize a pergunta com o link do fiddle e o código. Melhor colocar a informação relevante na própria pergunta, pra gente achar só de bater o olho.

Answer (score 2):

O que você quer é isso:

http://jsfiddle.net/greypants/zgCb7/

Edite a div abaixo com o conteúdo que você deseja:

```
<div class="tooltip">I am a tooltip!</div>
```

Comment: Exatamente Thallyson, muito obrigado